# How to hide .html extension in a Node.js server?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm using **express.js** in my Node server.

I have a webpage `https://example.com/login.html` and i want to be able to access it when typing `https://example.com/login`.

Since i'm used to **Apache** and **PHP** i know how to do it using `.htaccess` file but in Node.js i have no clue.

Comment: you have to create routes for it using express or other routing libs.

Comment: if you never worked on node with express then I will suggest you to follow this link. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Answer (score 13):

If there are a lot of HTML files, it may be favorable to use `express.static` instead of creating a route for each file:

```
app.use(express.static(htmlDir, { extensions: ['html'] }));
```

where `htmlDir` points to the directory containing your HTML files. This also works for subdirectories, e.g. `/pages` serves `pages.html` but `/pages/page1` serves `pages/page1.html`.

Check out [`serve-static`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html) for additional options such as defaulting to `index.html` or failing with 404 if no files match.

Answer (score 1):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('port', (5000));
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login'); // no need to use '.html'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple.

Put this at the top of your code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
```

And add this to your code

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html'); // replace /public with your directory
});
```